# How to extract email message and fill spreadsheet with values

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a macro that reads the unread messages in my inbox and extracts the data from the message with a delimiter of ":" . In the loop I want to be able to load the new excel spreadsheet with the values from the message.

I am able to select the first cell and save the data but it is getting over written. each time in the loop I want the data to go to the next cell in the column that is empty instead of overwriting the same cell.

Here is my code so far...

```
Public Sub Application_NewMail()

Dim newbk As Workbook
Set newbk = Workbooks.Add
newbk.SaveAs "C:\Users\RickG\Desktop\test2.xlsx"  'other parameters can  be set here if required
' perform operations on newbk
newbk.Close savechanges:=True

Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim InBoxFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim InBoxItem As Object 'MailItem
Dim Contents As String, Delimiter As String
Dim Prop, Result
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

'Setup an array with all properties that can be found in the mail
Prop = Array("Name", "Email", "Phone", "Customer Type", _
"Message")
'The delimiter after the property
Delimiter = ":"

 Set ns = Session.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")


'Access the inbox folder
Set InBoxFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
With xlApp
    .Visible = False
    Set xlWB = .Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\RickG\Desktop\test2.xlsx", , False)
    Set ws = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
 End With
Dim LR As Long

For Each InBoxItem In InBoxFolder.Items

'Only process mails
If Not TypeOf InBoxItem Is MailItem Then GoTo SkipItem
'Skip wrong subjects
If InStr(1, InBoxItem.Subject, "FW: New Lead - Consumer - Help with Medical Bills", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then GoTo SkipItem
'Already processed?
If Not InBoxItem.UnRead Then GoTo SkipItem
'Mark as read
InBoxItem.UnRead = False
'Get the body
Contents = InBoxItem.Body
'Create space for the result
ReDim Result(LBound(Prop) To UBound(Prop)) As String
'Search each property
i = 1

For k = LBound(Prop) To UBound(Prop)

  'Find the property (after the last position)
  i = InStr(i, Contents, Prop(k), vbTextCompare)
  If i = 0 Then GoTo NextProp
  'Find the delimiter after the property
  i = InStr(i, Contents, Delimiter)
  If i = 0 Then GoTo NextProp
  'Find the end of this line
  j = InStr(i, Contents, vbCr)
  If j = 0 Then GoTo NextProp
  'Store the related part
  Result(k) = Trim$(Mid$(Contents, i + Len(Delimiter), j - i - Len(Delimiter)))
  'for every row, find the first blank cell and select it
'MsgBox Result(k)
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A" & LR).Value = Result(k)
  'Update the position
  i = j

NextProp:
Next

xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
xlWB.SaveAs ("C:\Users\RickG\Desktop\test2.xlsx")
xlWB.Close
xlApp.Quit

If MsgBox(Join(Result, vbCrLf), vbOKCancel, "Auto Check In") = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
SkipItem:
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Change `Range("A" & LR).Value = Result(k)` to `Range("A" & LR+1).Value = Result(k)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not tracking your loop correctly. If you change

```
Range("A" & LR).Value = Result(k)
```

to

```
Range("A" & LR + 1).Value = Result(k)
```

in your

```
For k = LBound(Prop) To UBound(Prop)
```

loop, that should correct your issue.

EDIT: Sorry, findwindow. I didn't see the comment thread below the question. I just saw that the question had no answer yet.